# How to implement media Queries with Radium inside Material UI component

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, radium

Trying to implement breakpoint in Material UI component, Raised button.
Working for normal div's but not for Material UI component

Tried wrapping button inside radium

```
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
const RadiumRaisedButton = Radium(RaisedButton);
```

Followed by

```
<RadiumRaisedButton
  key={i}
  style={styles.buttonStyle}
  backgroundColor={color}
  labelColor={white}
  labelStyle={styles.labelStyle}
  onMouseEnter={() => {this.setState({hoverItem: i})}}
  onMouseLeave={() => {this.setState({hoverItem: currentRating})}}
  onClick={() => {this.setState({currentRating: i})}}
  label={category}
  type='button'
/>
```

and button style is

```
buttonStyle: {
  width: 200,
  '@media screen and (max-width:700px)': {
    width: 200,
  },
}
```

Can you help me here, its working in case of labelStyle prop of Raised button but not with style which is required.
Tried both versions `max-width:700px` and `maxWidth:700px` - nothing happens.

Comment: I think it's not possible for now buddy: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium/issues/586

Answer (score 0):

Please use a brace pair for writing media query, this fix your problem:

```
buttonStyle: {
  width: 200,
  ['@media screen and (max-width:700px)']: {
    width: 100,
  },
};
```